# Curve intercept as text on y-axis: ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, graphics, statistics

I'm trying to put the model's intercept value on the y-axis.
The code I'm using is this:

```
library(ggplot2)

mod <- lm(circumference ~ age + I(age^2), Orange); summary(mod)
novo_dados <- data.frame(age = seq(0, max(Orange$age), length.out = 100))
valores_previstos <- predict(mod, newdata = novo_dados)
intercepto <- coef(mod)[1]

ggplot(data = Orange, aes(x = age, y = circumference)) +
  geom_point(color = "black", shape = 19, size = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,1600), ylim = c(0,250)) +
  geom_line(data = novo_dados, aes(x = age, y = valores_previstos), 
            color = "black", linewidth = 2) +
  labs(title = "Quadratic Model",
       x = "Age",
       y = "Circumference") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, intercepto, max(Orange$circumference)), 
                     labels = c("0", round(intercepto, 2), max(Orange$circumference))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100, 200, 250), labels = c("0", "100", "200", "250")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_text(size = 30),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 30),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
```

The result of the code above is:

[image]

But notice that it is disappearing with the information associated with including the intercept value on the y-axis as text, that is:

```
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, intercepto, max(Orange$circumference)), 
                     labels = c("0", round(intercepto, 2), max(Orange$circumference)))
```

When I run the graph considering only the part described above, I have what I want, however the y axis only displays the maximum value of the y variable.

```
ggplot(data = Orange, aes(x = age, y = circumference)) +
  geom_point(color = "black", shape = 19, size = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,1600), ylim = c(0,250)) +
  geom_line(data = novo_dados, aes(x = age, y = valores_previstos), 
            color = "black", linewidth = 2) +
  labs(title = "Quadratic Model",
       x = "Age",
       y = "Circumference") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, intercepto, max(Orange$circumference)), 
                     labels = c("0", round(intercepto, 2), max(Orange$circumference))) +
#  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100, 200, 250), labels = c("0", "100", "200", "250")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_text(size = 30),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 30),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]

I would like the intercept value to appear on the y-axis but not have changes in the other y-axis values, that is, for it to remain normal.

Comment: Try with one scale_y_continuous, i.e. do `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, intercepto, max(Orange$circumference), 100, 200, 250))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two y scales will indeed apply only the last one specified to the plot:

```
Scale for y is already present.
Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.
```

But you can include both intercept and y-axis values to the same scale:

```
head(Orange)
library(ggplot2)

mod <- lm(circumference ~ age + I(age^2), Orange)
novo_dados <- data.frame(age = seq(0, max(Orange$age), length.out = 100))
valores_previstos <- predict(mod, newdata = novo_dados)
intercepto <- coef(mod)[1]

ggplot(data = Orange, aes(x = age, y = circumference)) +
  geom_point(color = "black", shape = 19, size = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1600), ylim = c(0, 250)) +
  geom_line(data = novo_dados, aes(x = age, y = valores_previstos), 
            color = "black", linewidth = 2) +
  labs(title = "Quadratic Model",
       x = "Age",
       y = "Circumference") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, intercepto, 100, 200, 250), 
                     labels = c("0", round(intercepto, 2), "100", "200", "250")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_text(size = 30),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", hjust = 1),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 30),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have the intercept values on the y-axis scale? You just need to adjust the y-axis but without dropping the original break points you want as follow:

```r
head(Orange)
library(ggplot2)

mod <- lm(circumference ~ age + I(age^2), Orange); summary(mod)
novo_dados <- data.frame(age = seq(0, max(Orange$age), length.out = 100))
valores_previstos <- predict(mod, newdata = novo_dados)
intercepto <- coef(mod)[1]

ggplot(data = Orange, aes(x = age, y = circumference)) +
  geom_point(color = "black", shape = 19, size = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,1600), ylim = c(0,250)) +
  geom_line(data = novo_dados, aes(x = age, y = valores_previstos), 
            color = "black", linewidth = 2) +
  labs(title = "Quadratic Model",
       x = "Age",
       y = "Circumference") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, intercepto, max(Orange$circumference), 100, 200, 250), ## Include the original breaks
                     labels = c("0", round(intercepto, 2), max(Orange$circumference), "100", "200", "250")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20), ## Adjust text size for clarity
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 15), ## Adjust text size for clarity
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]